# S3 Batch: time to copy 1m objects between buckets in the same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, batch-processing

I need to copy 92 million objects from bucket A to bucket B in the same AWS region.
I know AWS takes 48 hours to generate an S3 Inventory report, so ...
I'm wondering how long it takes to read a manifest of 92 million objects and copy them to another bucket.
My object files have an average size of 512KB.

Comment: Side-question: Is this a one-off requirement, or something you'll be doing regularly? If it is a repeating task, you could use **Same Region Replication** to copy objects created _in future_.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this is a one-off requirement.

Comment: Might be useful: [Transfer Large Amounts of Data Between Amazon S3 Buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [S3DistCp - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html), which fires off many parallel copy commands from a Hadoop cluster.

This involves a fair bit of overhead (using an Amazon EMR cluster), but once going it can copy the files quite rapidly by generating parallel API requests to copy the objects.

If you are going to instigate the copy yourself, then you could try something similar to generate many parallel copy requests, rather than simply looping through the list sequentially.